# Why would json_encode return an empty string

Tags: php, json

I have a simple php structure with 3 nested arrays.

I do not use particular objects and I build myself the arrays with 2 nested loops.

Here is a sample of the var_dump of the array I want to convert to Json.

```
array (size=2)
  'tram B' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'name' => string 'Ile Verte' (length=9)
          'distance' => int 298
          'stationID' => int 762
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'name' => string 'La Tronche Hôpital' (length=18)
          'distance' => int 425
          'stationID' => int 771
  16 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'name' => string 'Bastille' (length=8)
          'distance' => int 531
          'stationID' => int 397
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'name' => string 'Xavier Jouvin' (length=13)
          'distance' => int 589
          'stationID' => int 438
```

In another script I have a similar structure and `json_encode` works fine.
So I don't understand why `json_encode` won't work here.

Edit : there seems to be a problem with the encoding. When `mb_detect_encoding` returns ASCII, the `json_encode` works but when it returns UTF8, it doesn't work anymore.

Edit2 : `json_last_error()` returns `JSON_ERROR_UTF8` which means : [Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php).

Comment: PHP manual says `This function only works with UTF-8 encoded data.` so there shouldn't be any problem with encoding.

Comment: Try to use `utf8_encode()` on your `name` array fields before you hand the string to `json_encode()`.

Comment: Thx ! I just came myself to this solution which solved my problem.

Comment: Yeah, saw the answer. Good luck.

Comment: Use [`JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR` option](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-parameters) to see the problem (eg. the field with UTF8 will be null).

Comment: So it sounds like it should be returning false in the case of bad input.  From the docs: `Returns a JSON encoded string on success or false on failure.` Nobody here has answered why empty string is returned instead of false.

Answer (score 299, accepted):

Well after 2 hours of digging (cf Edits)

I found out following :

- In my case it's a encoding problem
- `mb_detect_encoding` returns probably a faulty response, some strings were probably not UTF-8
- using `utf8_encode()` on those string solved my problem, but see note below

Here is a recursive function that can force convert to UTF-8 all the strings contained in an array:

```
function utf8ize($d) {
    if (is_array($d)) {
        foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
            $d[$k] = utf8ize($v);
        }
    } else if (is_string ($d)) {
        return utf8_encode($d);
    }
    return $d;
}
```

Use it simply like this:

```
echo json_encode(utf8ize($data));
```

Note: [utf8_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) encodes ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8 as per the docs so if you are unsure of the input encoding [iconv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) or [mb_convert_encoding()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) may be better options as noted in comments and other solutions.

Comment: What about passing it on  ? :)

Comment: I should add that this problem showed up for me right after dumping a MySQL DB from a Windows server and moving it to an Ubuntu server. Must have been something in the dump.

Comment: Use [`JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR` option](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#refsect1-function.json-encode-parameters) to see the problem (eg. the field with UTF8 will be null).

Comment: If reading from the database just use, $conn->set_charset("utf8");

Comment: PHP developers should embed this utf8 option in the command's parameters!

Comment: Thank you for this. And if you need foreign characters change:
`return utf8_encode($d);`
to:
`return iconv(mb_detect_encoding($d), "UTF-8", $d);`

Comment: As of PHP 8.2.0, `utf8_encode()` is deprecated. Replacing `utf8_encode($d)` with `iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $d)` seems to be a good workaround. @dbx's use of `mb_detect_encoding($d)` may be needed if `'ISO-8859-1'` doesn't work.

Answer (score 42):

For me, the answer to this problem was setting `charset=utf8` in my PDO connection.

```
$dbo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdb;charset=utf8', $username, $password);
```

Comment: Or in mysqli functions: mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");

Comment: This was the hint to my solution. Little different cause of msqli connection. Just call `$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");` after doing your database handling.

Comment: Please use ``utf8mb4`` in recent MySQL versions. `utf8` is obsolete.

Answer (score 40):

Matthieu Riegler presented really good solution however I had to slightly modify it to handle objects too:

```
function utf8ize($d) {
    if (is_array($d)) 
        foreach ($d as $k => $v) 
            $d[$k] = utf8ize($v);

     else if(is_object($d))
        foreach ($d as $k => $v) 
            $d->$k = utf8ize($v);

     else 
        return utf8_encode($d);

    return $d;
}
```

One more note: [json_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) may be helpful in debugging json_encode()/json_encode() functions.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `elseif` instead of `else if`? (i.e. no blank).

Comment: @UweKeim according to the PHP documentation "elseif and else if will only be considered exactly the same when using curly brackets" which means they are equivalents as long as you don't use the colon notation e.g. `if(): elseif:`

Comment: You should insert a `else if(is_int($d)||is_bool($d))   return $d;` before the last else, because of: `{"success":true, "message":"Ⲃⲟⲟⲉⲁⲛ ⲁⲛⲇ Ⲓⲛϯⲉⲉꞅ"}`

Comment: Just like @paul-peelen recommended to @matthieu-riegler: Change the the last `else` for `else if(is_string ($d))`; otherwise you will be changing everything to strings (e.g. `INT` will become a `STRING`).

Comment: Also the json_last_error_msg() function will return a more user-friendly message as to why this is failing.

Comment: that final `return $d;` will never be called.

Answer (score 10):

Adam Bubela also presented really good solution who helped me solved my problem, and here is the simplified function :

```
function utf8ize($d)
{ 
    if (is_array($d) || is_object($d))
        foreach ($d as &$v) $v = utf8ize($v);
    else
        return utf8_encode($d);

    return $d;
}
```

Comment: I like this one as it preserves the keys.

Answer (score 7):

I have exactly the same problem on PHP 5.6.
I use [Open Server](https://ospanel.io/) + Nginx on Windows 7. All charsets are set to UTF-8.
In theory, according the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php), flag

> JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE

should solve this. 
Unfortunately this is not my case. I do not know, why. All snippets above do not solve my problem, thus I have found my own implementation. I believe it could help someone. At least, Russian letters pass the test.

```
function utf8ize($d) {
    if (is_array($d) || is_object($d)) {
        foreach ($d as &$v) $v = utf8ize($v);
    } else {
        $enc   = mb_detect_encoding($d);

        $value = iconv($enc, 'UTF-8', $d);
        return $value;
    }

    return $d;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This accepted answer works. But in case you are getting your data from MySQL (as I was) there is an easier way.

Once you open you database, before you query you can set the character set using mysqli as follows:

```
/* change character set to utf8 | Procedural*/
if (!mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
    exit();
}
```

OR

```
/* change character set to utf8 | Object Oriented*/
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) {
        printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
        exit();
 }
```

LINK: 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: Note: $mysqli is the name of the variable that you populated when you created your mysql connection. Your variable name may vary.

Example $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db, $port);

In addition, as mentioned in the comments above, recommend using utf8mb4 rather than utf8 for newer versions of MySql.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue on a server running an older version of PHP (5.2). I was using the JSON_FORCE_OBJECT flag, and apparently that isn't supported until 5.3

So if you're using that flag be sure to check your version!

A workaround appears to be just casting to an object before encoding, like:

```
json_encode((object)$myvar);
```

Answer (score 4):

I was getting data from ob_get_clean() and had the same problem, but above solutions don't work for me. In my case solution was this, maybe it will help somebody.

```
$var = mb_convert_encoding($var, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 3):

The return of `mb_detect_encoding` may not be correct:

```
$data = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', 'La Tronche Hôpital');
var_dump(
    mb_detect_encoding($data),
    mb_detect_encoding($data, array('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8'))
);
```

Depending on the default detection order, the above may return different results, so the encoding is falsely being reported as UTF-8. ([Here's a larger example](http://3v4l.org/i7WEC).)

It is likely that your data is not encoded as UTF-8, so `json_encode` is returning `false`. You should look at converting your strings to UTF-8 before JSON-encoding:

```
$fromEncoding = 'ISO-8859-1'; // This depends on the data

array_walk_recursive($array, function (&$value, $key, $fromEncoding) {
    if (is_string($value)) {
        $value = iconv($fromEncoding, 'UTF-8', $value);
    }
}, $fromEncoding);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have improved Adam Bubela's answer.
I just hate it when blocks are not closed by { and }.
It's cleaner and you don't introduce bugs or maybe it's that I did use Perl in the past :)

```
<?php

class App_Updater_String_Util {    
    /**
     * Usage: App_Updater_String_Util::utf8_encode( $data );
     *
     * @param mixed $d
     * @return mixed
     * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361282/why-would-json-encode-returns-an-empty-string
     */
    public static function utf8_encode($d) {
        if (is_array($d)) {
            foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
                $d[$k] = self::utf8_encode($v);
            }
        } elseif (is_object($d)) {
            foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
                $d->$k = self::utf8_encode($v);
            }
        } elseif (is_scalar($d)) {
            $d = utf8_encode($d);
        }

        return $d;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Great answer which greatly inspired me, and I propose an evolution that I submit as a response

Answer (score 2):

Since the output is going to end up as JSON (string) anyway, here is a function that can handle all kind of variable type:

```php
    function utf8ize($arg)
    {
        if (is_array($arg))
            foreach ($arg as $k => $v)
                $arg[$k] = utf8ize($v);
         else if(is_object($arg))
            return utf8ize((array) $arg);
         else
            return utf8_encode(strval($arg));
        return $arg;
    }
```

This answer is improvement from Matthieu Riegler and Adam Bubela's answer, but this one can handle all type of variable / data type (e.g.: resource like file handle/stream/phpgd/sql connection)

I'm using cast as array when the argument is object in order to prevent error if the object property is read only or private/protected.

Also, on `else` case, I `strval` it to handle other data type like `resource`

I'm using this function to 'force' a variable into string (e.g.: when var_dump-ing or logging to text file)

Answer (score 1):

using utf8_encode() on those string solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this data from a database, use  `mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");` in connection when get the params from database

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason for the API returning an empty JSON was that the properties of the object were set to **private**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the [Matthieu Riegler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884123)'s answer code since years, but recently I faced to new issues and after reading [Svetoslav Marinov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86771/svetoslav-marinov)'s answer, I have worked on a modern evolution of the provided script. I have added it as a [gist in my Github profile](https://gist.github.com/w3spi5/942cb38d687b9bebb449eb671d4c177a), you can also find it below :

```
public static function utf8ize($d)
{
    if (is_array($d)) {
        foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
            $d[$k] = self::utf8ize($v);
        }
    } elseif (is_object($d)) {
        // Recursively convert object properties
        $vars = get_object_vars($d);
        foreach ($vars as $k => $v) {
            $d->$k = self::utf8ize($v);
        }
    } elseif (is_string($d)) {
        // Try a list of common encodings before converting
        $encodings = ['UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', 'Windows-1251', 'Windows-1252', 'GB2312', 'BIG5'];
        foreach ($encodings as $encoding) {
            if (mb_check_encoding($d, $encoding)) {
                return mb_convert_encoding($d, 'UTF-8', $encoding);
            }
        }
        // Use 'auto' as a last resort
        return mb_convert_encoding($d, 'UTF-8', 'auto');
    }
    return $d;
}
```