# PDO result array cannot be turned into json

Tags: php, pdo, json

I've seen many examples on the internet (especially here) where the solution below should be able to turn the result of a database query into JSON:

```
    $stmt = $pdo->query('select * from TABLE;');
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($data);
```

but in my case this doesn't produce any JSON, although the query result contains 75 rows. A slightly different approach does return JSON:

```
    $stmt = $pdo->query('select * from TABLE;');
    echo "[";
    while($r = $stmt->fetch()) {
        echo json_encode($r);
    }
    echo "]";
```

I could go with that, but I am wondering what is going on. Why is the first approach not working?

EDIT:

this might give a clue. The code below produces [] as a result. Still not what I want, but the fetch in the while statement does 'something' .

```
    $stmt = $pdo->query('select * from TABLE;');
    while($r = $stmt->fetch()) {}
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "doesn't produce any JSON"?

Comment: I get an empty string

Comment: Do you realize that it simple can't be? If second query returns something, then firs will return a well.

Comment: Make sure your data is encoded correctly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361282/why-would-json-encode-returns-an-empty-string

Comment: @YourCommonSense because he is using `->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: @tlenss what? "because"? May be you can explain, how this code can make any sense when used with ->fetchAll?

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the first approach not working?

It does. Just double check the resulting JSON.
As long as your query returns any rows, this code produces perfect, first class json.

Most likely, like other PHP users, you are checking not the immediate result but distant consequences.

If it really doesn't, then check json_last_error() and then set your database client encoding in utf8

Comment: What do you mean that I am checking distant consequences?

Comment: I mean you are checking anything but json returned by this code. May be some image in the browser or something like that.

Comment: json_last_error() returns 5 which apparently means that I have a problem with the utf8 encoding.I will look into it. Thanks for showing me the right direction!

Comment: @WalterBrand if first code returns nothing, then second should return the same.

Comment: somehow the second one produces json.