# How to debug silent failure of massive PHP application?

Tags: php, linux, debugging

In the code below, the string "hi" is never outputted.

The `MainDispatcher` class is just the boostrap of a massive framework with a large application underneath it, which was "working fine until the other day" (I have tried to `git-bisect` it but that's a story for another post).

How can I find out where the code is silently terminating execution?

```
require_once "autoload/classes.php";

try {

        $main = new MainDispatcher(root());

        if ($main->httpHeaders()) {
                $main->handleRequest();
        }
echo 'hi';
}
catch(Exception $e) {
echo 'hi';
        Log::error($e, $main->config->traceLog);
}
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting?

Comment: Maybe `MainDispatcher` has a die() or exit() in there somewhere.

Comment: Finally tracked it down to a UTF8 & json_encode issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361282/why-would-json-encode-returns-an-empty-string

Answer (score 0):

Move your `require_once` call inside the TRY block because if this is failing, it doesn't get caught.

Also, if you're unsure how to access the logs and are just debugging, print the exceptions rather than logging them. So in the CATCH block, add a `echo $e->getMessage();`.

I think you should start seeing the cause of your problem.