# Select2 return "({"ok": 1, "total": 7, "rows": })" and display loading failed

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

When I'm using select2 with my database on localhost. It works correctly. 
But when I'm using with database on server, eg 10.0.0.1 it doesn't work.

Here's my select2 script :

```
$('#slDrug').select2({
    placeholder: 'ค้นหาเวชภัณฑ์',
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    allowClear: true,
    language: "th",
    ajax: {
        url: 'ajax/drugSearch.php',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'GET',
        quietMillis: 100,
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                query: term,
                start: page,
                stop: 20
            };
        }, results: function (data, page) {
            var more = (page * 10) < data.total;
            return { results: data.rows, more: more };
        }
    }, id: function(data) {
        return { id: data.code }
    }, formatResult: function(data) {
        return '[ ' + data.code + ' ] ' + data.name + ' ความแรง : ' + data.strength + ' หน่วยนับ : ' + data.units;
    }, formatSelection: function(data) {
        return data.code + '  ' + data.name + ' ' + data.strength;
    }
});
```

And here's my php code :

```
<?php

require_once('../require/medoo.min.php');

// Select connectinfo from database
$localDB = new medoo();
$getHosInfo = $localDB->select("sys_config","*");
foreach($getHosInfo as $g){
    $host = $g['host'];
    $user = $g['user'];
    $pass = $g['password'];
    $dbname = $g['dbname'];
}

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$dsn = 'mysql:host='.$host.'; dbname='.$dbname.'; charset=utf8';

try {
    $conn = new PDO( $dsn, $user, $pass);
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
} catch ( PDOException $e ) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$query      = $_GET['query'];
$callback   = $_GET['callback'];

$start      = $_GET['start'];
$stop       = $_GET['stop'];

$start      = empty($start) ? 1 : $start;
$stop       = empty($stop) ? 10 : $stop;

$start      = ($start - 1) * $stop;

$sql_total  = 'select count(*) as total from drugitems where name like "%' . $query . '%"';

$st = $conn->prepare($sql_total);
$st->execute();
$rows_total = $st->fetch();

$sql_rows = 'select icode, name, strength,units,unitcost,unitprice,did,antibiotic,fp_drug
                 from drugitems
                 where name like "%' . $query . '%" limit ' . $start . ', ' . $stop;

$st = $conn->prepare($sql_rows);
$st->execute();

$rows_result = $st->fetchAll();

$data = array();

foreach($rows_result as $r)
{
    $obj = new stdClass();
    $obj->code = $r['icode'];
    $obj->name = $r['name'];
    $obj->strength = $r['strength'];
    $obj->did = $r['did'];
    $obj->unitprice = $r['unitprice'];
    $obj->unitcost = $r['unitcost'];
    $obj->units = $r['units'];
    $obj->antibiotic = $r['antibiotic'];
    $obj->fp_drug = $r['fp_drug'];

    $data[] = $obj;
}

$json = '{"ok": 1, "total": ' . $rows_total['total'] . ', "rows": ' . json_encode($data) . '}';

echo $callback . '(' . $json . ')';

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would json_encode returns an empty string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19361282/689579)

Comment: Try getting the php output in console using `console.log`. You'll either get the output or the error thrown.