# Converting an array of items from SQL query into JSON using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have used the code below to extract the data from my database and convert it into an array. My problem is that the echo json_encode function does not work and when running this code (without the print_r function) I am left with a blank page.

```
$query = "SELECT * From table";

$resultarray = array();

if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

         $resultarray[] = $row;    
     }

     print_r($resultarray); // This line shows that the array is works but the code below does not convert to JSON.

     echo json_encode($resultarray);
}
```

I have used the print_r function to make sure that I have created an array within my code. I have gone around in circles for hours and I do not understand what I am doing wrong. If I use the print_r function and view the page source I get the following:

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => Name 1
        [2] => Description 1
        [3] => Location 1

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6
        [1] => Name 2
        [2] => Description 2
        [3] => Location 2

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 45
        [1] => Name 3
        [2] => Description 3
        [3] => Location 3

    )
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you figured out You're missing a quote to close the string at the first line?

Comment: This [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19366999/4018240) might be helpful for you...

Comment: Thanks @ManjeetBarnala Problem solved. I looked into this and solved it by adding the following:   mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");

Comment: Cool !!... glad to help you @Brett

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add double quotation on this line:

`$query = "SELECT * From table;`

and because of that internal server error has occurred.

first line code should be like this

`$query = "SELECT * From table";`

Comment: Good spot, but that is not the issue. I edited the $query when pasting it in stack overflow to make the code clearer but missed the ending ". The code that I am running has this and it query is executed in the database. I'm having issues converting my array into JSON.

Comment: Please check above answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql ="SELECT * FROM `table_name`";
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
       $resultarray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($resultarray);
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root","db_rest");
$query = "SELECT * From users";
$resultarray = array();
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
         $resultarray[] = $row;   
 
     }
     echo json_encode($resultarray);
}