# AJAX returns error with empty responseText

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get some data trough AJAX but am getting an error with an empty responseText.

My code is as follows:

JS:

```
function getFounder(id) {
    var founder = "";

    $.ajax({ 

        url: '/data/founder_info.php',
        data: {founder: id},
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(json) {

            //founder = json.username;

            console.log(json);

        },
        error: function(ts) {
            console.log("Error: " + ts.responseText);
        }
    });

    return founder;
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php

require_once '../core/init.php';

if($_POST['founder']) {

    $u = new User();

    $user_info = $u->find(escape($_POST['founder']));
    $user_info = $u->data();

    echo json_encode($user_info);
    exit();
}
```

I cannot find the issue as to why it is throwing the error.

Comment: What is the output of : console.log(json);

Comment: @MayankPandey It wont even get to that as it throws the error

Comment: In that case check console to get the error in php call

Comment: Look in your network tab in the Developers tools of your browser. See what the response is

Comment: `am getting an error` - that's a good start. A good next step would be to share with us the error you are getting, because there are so many possibilities, we could be here all night before we stumbled upon what the error is - you have an advantage, you obviously have an error message!

Comment: as an aside - synchronous XMLHttpRequests (yes, that's what you have there) are deprecated in most decent browsers these days - when you get this issue resolved, learn how to deal with asynchronous requests (and code in general)

Comment: @JaromandaX The error responseText is blank

Comment: @PatrickEvans I see no errors in the network tab

Comment: yes, because it would be, an error wont have responseText, as there is no responseText if there's an error (usually) ... console.log(ts); then inspect the object

Comment: You need to display errors in your php script or check the web-server error log.

Comment: at first glance `$user_info = $u->find(escape($_POST['founder']));$user_info = $u->data();` - this looks wrong

Comment: @Chris, didn't say you would, said look at the response, meaning find the request that matches `/data/founder_info.php` and see what the server responded with

Comment: @PatrickEvans The reponse tab is empty as well. What does this mean?

Comment: have a look at the jquery documentation about [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) - note that there are THREE parameters passed to the error callback - you've cherry picked a single property of the first one as a error message - you picked wrong, try all three arguments to get a real sense of what you've done wrong

Comment: the response tab will be empty ( `ts.responseText` proved that ) - which browser are you using - perhaps you need more precise guidance in how to use your browsers developer tools for debugging

Comment: @JaromandaX using Chrome

Comment: Means your php script isn't outputting anything, look at your server logs make sure the script isn't silently erroring out, check that `$u->data()` actually returns something that can encoded into JSON

Comment: @PatrickEvans I used `die()` to check on that. It outputs the correct data.

Comment: so, you don't even see `/data/founder_info.php` in the developer tools network tab? if so, can you see the status (is it 200? 404? 500? something else)

Comment: @JaromandaX It has status 200

Comment: ok, so now change your `error:` to `error: function(a, b, c) { console.log(a, b, c); }` - see if there's anything at all useful logged in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using a method to convert everything to UTF-8.

```
function utf8ize($d) {
    if (is_array($d)) 
        foreach ($d as $k => $v) 
            $d[$k] = utf8ize($v);

     else if(is_object($d))
        foreach ($d as $k => $v) 
            $d->$k = utf8ize($v);

     else 
        return utf8_encode($d);

    return $d;
}
```

This was posted as an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361282/why-would-json-encode-returns-an-empty-string)

My problem is now solved!