# Unexpected end of JSON input - Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

everybody. I have an AJAX call which returns me an error mentioned in the title. I believe this is the line which causes error: `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);` Maybe I wrongly constructed `userData`.

This is my jQuery:

```
var userData = 'email=' + email + '&password=' + password; 

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: './api/getInfo.php',
    data: userData,
    success: function(data){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 

        $('#name').html(obj.firstName + ' ' + obj.lastName);
        ...
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('ERROR');
    }
});
```

And this is getInfo.php:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
     $email = prepareInput($_POST['email']);
     $password = prepareInput($_POST['password']);

     $stmt = $connection->conn->prepare('SELECT firstName,lastName,... FROM tb_users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?');
     $stmt->bind_param('ss',$email,$password);

     $stmt->execute();

     $result = $stmt->get_result();

     $obj = $result->fetch_assoc();

     echo json_encode($obj);
}
```

Can someone tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**

```
function prepareInput($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

    return $data;
}
```

Data passed from PHP is empty even if `$obj` contains values (I checked this by echoing them) so it must be the problem with `echo json_encode($obj);` statement.

**SOLUTION**

I finally found the answer - **[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361282/why-would-json-encode-returns-an-empty-string)**. It was **encoding problem**. If some strings are not UTF-8 `json_encode()` will return empty string so to deal with this you need to convert these strings to UTF-8.

Comment: add a `console.log(data)` as first line in the success handler to check the server response. I bet there is some extra code at the end/before your JSON string that causes the error...

Comment: try adding dataType:"json" in your ajax call

Comment: You should use an object as ajax `data` instead of building a string by your own. Like this: `data: { email: email, password: password }`.

Comment: @Philipp I tried this but there is no response. @Mir If I add `dataType: 'json'` error occurs.

Comment: @eisbehr If change this, error is still there.

Comment: Sorry, my comment didn't meant so wolve the error, it is just a better practice and was a hint for you.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the tip.

Comment: The `prepareInput` function looks okay, though I'd remove the htmlspecialchars() call here; it does not make too much sense. I added some notes on debugging the SQL in my answer below

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention: the success function does not receive any data

It seems the server response is empty, because (a) the credentials are wrong or (b) there is an error in PHP and your code never reaches the `echo` line.

Add some error handling / confirmation in PHP and make sure that $obj has a value before you return it.

```
try {
  // ... sql code

  if ( $obj && is_array( $obj ) ) {
    echo json_encode( $obj );
  } else {
    echo json_encode( array( 'error' => 'wrong username or password' ) );
  }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo json_encode( array( 'error' => $ex->getMessage() ) );
}
```

**Update; notes for debugging the SQL**

To test the SQL:

1. As first line in the condition (method == POST) add `echo json_encode(array('resp'=>'test')); exit;` and run the Ajax code. 
   Your `console.log()` should now display the {resp:test} JSON object. This way you know that your ajax call actually reaches the part with the SQL. If you still do not get any output then something else is wrong in your code...
2. First use a hardcoded SQL: Just enter email/password in WHERE that you know will give you a result. Do not use `->bind_param()` or `$_POST` data, just execute a plain SQL statement and see if AJAX returns a value.
3. If Ajax works now, then modify the hardcoded SQL to move the static email/password string into `bind_param()`. Still not using `$_POST` data now, but we check if the bind_param method works. Again check if Ajax is still working.
4. If still working, then use direkt $_POST data in the bind_param() call, like `->bind_param('ss', $_POST['email'], $_POST['password'])` - if this is working, *then* you know that there's a problem with the prepareInput() function.

When testing each step, you should quickly find out, which part is not working.

Comment: I have tested each of these four steps and everything is working fine. Array `$obj` has values (I checked this by echoing its values) but somehow `echo json_encode($obj);` returns nothing to AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to check if your `execute` is a success before you use the result.

If I was you I will try to `console.log(data)` before use `jsonParse`. I think you will find some surprise.

Also, check your apache logs. Maybe PHP throw you some warnings in it.

Comment: I already tried `console.log(data)` but nothing is written to console. Also there are no errors or warning in Apache logs.

Comment: I suspect the SQL is wrong; maybe your `prepareInput()` modifies the password or email address and the SQL returns no result.