# Php Script empty response get data

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, server-side

I'm trying to fix up an old script which used to always work but now gives an empty response; I have no idea why. I have checked that the while loop is entered, `num_of_rows = 100`, yet I don't get any response.

```
<?php

$response = array();


$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "***", "***","***");


// get all gamelists from gamelists table
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `abcd`");


// check for empty result
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {


$response["gamelist"] = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    // temp user array

    $gamelist = array();
    $gamelist["id"] = $row["id"];
    $gamelist["ques"] = $row["ques"];
    $gamelist["odp_a"] = $row["odp_a"];
    $gamelist["odp_b"] = $row["odp_b"];
    $gamelist["odp_c"] = $row["odp_c"];
    $gamelist["odp_d"] = $row["odp_d"];
    $gamelist["comment"] = $row["comment"];
    $gamelist["correctanswer"] = $row["correctanswer"];
    $gamelist["commentfirst"] = $row["commentfirst"];





    // push single gamelist into final response array

    array_push($response["gamelist"], $gamelist);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
 } else {
// no gamelists found
  $response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No gamelists found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
 }
?>
```

[image]

Output :

```
1234444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
```

Comment: The response to my get request is empty.

Comment: I am sending a `GET` request to this PHP script. The response is `EMPTY`

Comment: Basically nothing is echoed back, does that make sense?

Comment: just use the code of:-https://eval.in/634313. also check this file by running directly that json data is coming or not? Also add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` just after `<?php`. i forgot to add that

Comment: @Anant I added your code, I posted the screenshot of what I'm getting

Comment: What do you mean? I ran the SQL query on the database in phpmyAdmin, works fine, I also added lines like `echo("test");` to this file which also echo

Comment: @Anant I uploaded the current way the code looks, and the output it produces

Comment: @Anant same result as before

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361282/why-would-json-encode-returns-an-empty-string this solved it

Comment: utf-8 issue? dam god. good that you solved it, because your code never state that issue

Comment: Didn't think it was an issue, I imported a database and didn't realise it wasn't in utf-8... thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code seems to be working , but a better approach will be:-

```
<?php

$response = array();


$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "***", "***","***");

if($conn){
    // get all gamelists from gamelists table
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `abcd`");

    if($result){
        // check for empty result
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                $response["gamelist"][] = $row;
            }
            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response); exit;
        } else {
            // no gamelists found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No gamelists found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);exit;
        }
    }else{
        echo "db query error".mysqli_error($conn); exit;
    }
}else{
    echo "db connection error".mysqli_connect_error(); exit;
}
?>
```

Since you said that it's something related to utf-8 issue.

This link is what you found useful:-

[Why would json_encode returns an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361282/why-would-json-encode-returns-an-empty-string)