# PHP UTF-8 encoding echoes question marks

Tags: php, json, utf-8, echo, special-characters

I'm trying to echo a json_response with unicode characters using the following code:

```
function utf8ize($d) {
if (is_array($d)) {
    foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
        $d[$k] = utf8ize($v);
    }
} else if (is_string ($d)) {
    return utf8_encode($d);
}
return $d;
}
```

used like this:

```
echo json_encode(utf8ize($response));
```

The problem with this is that some characters are encoded properly and other characters like `ć` and `ś` are sent as question marks as seen in the below image:

[image]

I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: In which character encoding are the strings?

Comment: they are taken from my database which is in `utf8_polish_ci`

Comment: Then what do you expect `utf8_encode` to do? If they are already in UTF-8 a `utf8_encode` will just destroy them. [Docs](http://php.net/utf8_encode)

Comment: I added that because without it my php script didn't want to echo anything and I followed the suggestion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361282/why-would-json-encode-returns-an-empty-string after which it started returning the output shown

Comment: I'd recommend you to follow fayd's answer (the one with 8 upvotes) instead.

Comment: Use json_encode with JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE options

Comment: @tkausl I'm using `mysqli_connect` not PDO

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/3885509

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to execute

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

As a query. After you've made the connection.

Then just in case set this header

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

Then try again

Comment: `SET NAMES utf8` changed the output to this : `"Warto\u0139\u009b\u00c4\u0087 wyra\u0139\u017aenia 5 - 2 \u00c2\u02c7 4 jest r\u0102\u0142wna` That's still not displaying properly for me

Comment: Nevermind, after I deleted the utf8_encode it works fine. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if you have any html, but the use the header like `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` in that case

Comment: Nope, this is a PHP script called by a mobile app in Java, no HTML going on

Comment: Okay, but wanted to be sure. Haha

Answer (score 2):

> According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php
>   `utf8_encode` encodes data from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8.

However, Polish lang has iso-8859-2 charset so you should use

`iconv('iso-8859-2', 'utf-8', $d)` 
instead of `utf8_encode($d)`