# php json encode not output anything

Tags: php, sql, json

I have simple php script that shoud output json, but it dont work

```
<?php 

require 'connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM horizont";
$result = $con->query($sql);
$rows = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             $rows[] = $row;
    } 
} 
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($rows);
echo '</pre>';

echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

i get result on var dump , but not json code.

var dump result:

[image: http://prntscr.com/e0ef2c]

connect.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","horizont");

// Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
 ?>
```

Fixed with :

```
 $con->set_charset("utf8");
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19361282/2298301

Comment: json_encode returns false on failure; you should check that

Comment: What did you get on the var_dump? Update the question with the data

Comment: are you going to access the output with ajax?

Comment: var dump updated, yes i will access with ajax

Comment: ok check my answer

Comment: i tried var_dump(json_encode($rows)); , result  -> bool(false)

Comment: According to your `var_dump()` output the array is called `$resultArray` but your code does not do a `var_dump($resultArray);` **Please post the real code** PSEUDO CODE gets a PSEUDO ANSWER

Comment: show us your connect.php

Comment: its en encoding problem, try this `json_encode( $rows, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );`

Comment: connect.php added

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is real code, i updejtet picture

Comment: @mwweb tried, still same thing

Comment: Still not the output from this code. I am out of here, to late to fight for correct information

Comment: show us correct code. try this `mysql_set_charset("utf8", $con);` after `$con = ...` line

Comment: code is correct , i will try this

Comment: thanks man , it works with $con->set_charset("utf8");

Comment: @markomarinovic if you wat to access the output with ajax you have to add the header `header('Content-type: application/json');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For encoding problem try this:

```
$con->set_charset("utf8");
```