# Converting text array to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I'm trying to convert an array from a GET request to an actual object in Javascript.

This is an example of the array I'm trying to convert.

```
array(21) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(15508)
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Some name"
    ["API_key"]=>
    string(19) "Some key"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(19695)
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Some name"
    ["API_key"]=>
    string(19) "Some key"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(19627)
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "Some name"
    ["API_key"]=>
    string(19) "Some key"
  }
```

The array is generated form a web service server in PHP.

I've tried to do this:

```
var result = xmlHttp.responseText;
var string = JSON.stringify(result);
var json = JSON.parse(string);
```

This returns the same array, but when I try to access certain items in the array for example in a for-loop: `json[i]` returns a single letter as if the array was a string.

I have control of the server, and this is the code in the php file that handles the returning of the array:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
var_dump($result);
```

Using `gettype($result)` returns 'array'.

**Edit**

I was able to get PHP to return the array in JSON format:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 15508,
      "name": "Some name",
      "API_key": "Some key"
    },
    {
      "id": 19695,
      "name": "Some name",
      "API_key": "Some key"
    },
    {
      "id": 19627,
      "name": "Some name",
      "API_key": "Some key"
    {
  ]
]
```

I'm kinda new to this, and I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: try `json_encode` and then return

Comment: There's no point trying to use JSON tools on something that isn't JSON. But: Could you modify the PHP so it outputs JSON (via `json_encode`) rather than just dumping the variable in PHP format? *Then* you could use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(typeof result)` ?

Comment: @Weedoze: From the question, we know it'll be `"string"`. :-) (Since using `JSON.stringify` then `JSON.parse` didn't fail and gave him/her the same result.)

Comment: is the data from the web service sent exactly like this?

Comment: do you have control over the output of the web server?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right ! I wanted to be 100% sure

Comment: I've updated the question with the server code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder when trying that, the server code returns `bool(false)` for some reason.

@Weedoze `typeof result` returns `string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update! I solved it this way**

By using the code  in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19366999/7169727) answer, I was able to create JSON in PHP, as it turned out, my array was not properly encoded.

```
$arr[] = $result;
function utf8ize($d) {
    if (is_array($d)) {
        foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
            $d[$k] = utf8ize($v);
        }
    } else if (is_string ($d)) {
        return utf8_encode($d);
    }
    return $d;
```

Then using `echo json_encode(utf8ize($data));` returns the array to JSON. To transform it to JSON in JavaScript, I used the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47749190/7169727) here for help:

```
var result = xmlHttp.responseText;
var json = JSON.parse(result);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try in PHP

```
$json = json_encode($_GET);
print_r($json);
```

And in JS

```
var result = xmlHttp.responseText;
var json = JSON.parse(result);
```