# no json output for php code while reading data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to retrieve `mysql data` in `json` format using php, below is my code, but after execution I am getting blank output, if I check the output of the array elements using `var_dump()` then I can see the records but as a whole the `json` output is not showing, as i am new to `json` so not able to troubleshoot, can anyone check and find the problem, it will be great thnx.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'mypassword';
$dbname = 'mydbname';

//setting records limit per page is 15
$rec_limit = 15;

//Establishing Connection
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

/* Get total number of records */
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM ImageUploads";
$retval = $conn->query($sql);
if(! $retval )
{
  die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
}

$rec_count = $retval->fetch_row();
$rec_count = $rec_count[0];

// Checking for page parameter to set.
if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) )
{
   $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
   $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
}
else
{
   $page = 0;
   $offset = 0;
}

//getting all data from table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ImageUploads ORDER BY slno DESC ".
       "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";

$retval = $conn->query($sql);
if(! $retval )
{
 die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
}

//creating an array for response
 $response = array();

 if ($retval->num_rows > 0) {
 $response["wallpapers"] = array();
 $response["success"] = 1;
 $response["count"]= $rec_count;
 while ($row = $retval->fetch_array()) {
        // temp wallpaper array
        $wallpaper = array();
        $wallpaper["id"] = $row["slno"];
        $wallpaper["orig_url"] = "http://doupnow.com/AndroidApp/ImageUploads/".$row["image_url"];
        $wallpaper["thumb_url"]="No Thumb";
        $wallpaper["downloads"] = $row["downloads"];
        $wallpaper["fav"] = $row["views"];


        // push all data into final response array
        array_push($response["wallpapers"], $wallpaper);
    }

    // echoing JSON response
   echo str_replace('\/','/',json_encode($response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));

} else {
    // no wallpapers found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Wallpapers found";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

output of var_dump($response) is --

```
array(3) {
  ["wallpapers"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["orig_url"]=>
      string(95) "http://doupnow.com/AndroidApp/ImageUploads/raman.das@gmail.com_sOw$vN8T_IMG_20171203_200638.jpg"
      ["thumb_url"]=>
      string(8) "No Thumb"
      ["downloads"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["fav"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
  }
  ["success"]=>
  int(1)
  ["count"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Comment: This maybe related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361282/why-would-json-encode-return-an-empty-string

Comment: Show what you are getting in `$response` and in `var_dump` also

Comment: @YashParekh............the output of var_dump($response) is attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved, just a simple issue, thank god. i changed this line as --

```
echo str_replace('\/','/',json_encode($response));
//echo str_replace('\/','/',json_encode($response,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Now i am getting the json output.

Comment: After 2 days, you can accept your own answer, which will help others who read this question in future

Answer (score 0):

seems like there is a problem in your
$wallpaper["orig_url"] = "http://doupnow.com/AndroidApp/ImageUploads/".$row["image_url"];
remove the $row["image_url"]from this and test it.