# Laravel globally logging validation exceptions

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-8, laravel-validation

I have a request to log **all** validation exceptions in my application. I have all of it working except for the request parameters are empty. I'm able to `dd` the request parameters, and it displays, but it doesn't seem to log. How is the `$data` value getting wiped?

In `app\Exceptions\Handler.php`:

```php
public function report(Throwable $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof ValidationException) {
        $data = json_encode(collect(request()->all())->map(function ($value, $key) {
            return (in_array($key, $this->dontFlash)) ? '(redacted)' : $value;
        })->toArray());

        Log::info('[VALIDATION ERROR][' . request()->ip() . '][DATA] ' . $data . '[ERRORS] ' .
            json_encode($exception->errors()));
    }

    parent::report($exception);
}
```

Example log (see that $data is now null?):

> [VALIDATION ERROR][127.0.0.1][DATA] [ERRORS] {"email":["The email must
> be a valid email address."],"password":["The password must be at least
> 10 characters and contain at least one uppercase character, one
> number, and one special character."]}

Expected:

> [VALIDATION ERROR][127.0.0.1][DATA]
> {"_token":"JY5euwiygtZCCp02l9Jo1usHBywEruWywGnYy8ft","first_name":"f","last_name":"f","email":"f@fa","password":"(redacted)","password_confirmation":"(redacted)"}
> [ERRORS] {"email":["The email must be a valid email
> address."],"password":["The password must be at least 10 characters
> and contain at least one uppercase character, one number, and one
> special character."]}

--

```
$data = json_encode(collect(request()->all())->map(function ($value, $key) {
    return (in_array($key, $this->dontFlash)) ? '(redacted)' : $value;
})->toArray());

dd($data);
```

returns: `{"_token":"JY5euwiygtZCCp02l9Jo1usHBywEruWywGnYy8ft","first_name":"f","last_name":"f","email":"f@fa","password":"(redacted)","password_confirmation":"(redacted)"}`

What is causing this? How am I able to see the request parameters in the request? I've tried using reflection and extracting out the data from the `Validator` object, and that was empty too.

Comment: Terminable middleware might help you solve this problem. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#terminable-middleware

Comment: This may be the pbm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361282/why-would-json-encode-return-an-empty-string