# PHP not writing SQL result to JSON file

Tags: php, arrays, json, mysqli

What I am trying to achieve is to simply put all the rows of a mysqli result to a JSON file.

My code looks like this:

```
$sth = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM table");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print_r($rows);
$mysqli->close();
$fileobj = fopen("takeOutItems.json", 'w');
fwrite($fileobj,json_encode($rows));
fclose($fileobj);
```

printing the $rows arrays shows data correctly.
fwrite, however, does not change anything in **takeOutItems.json**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does print_r print in the browser with that data?

Comment: @Jerson yes, every single data field is shown in the browser. Updated my issue's description based on your question.

Comment: Is it possible that it has to do something with UTF8? there are some fields that show � signs instead the actual characters?

Comment: have you tried file_put_contents('takeOutItems.json',json_encode($rows)); ?

Comment: if it's does not working you'll need to check the directory permission.

Comment: @Jerson Just tried, yet, json file is still empty.

Comment: Can you try to print the json_encode using echo?, will see if the array is parse into json successfully.

Comment: echo json_encode($rows) not printing anything. Checked write permissions with is_writable and it is writeable.

Comment: You may see this, I think the possible problem is the encoding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361282/why-would-json-encode-return-an-empty-string

Comment: That was it! An encoding error resulted the errors. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that some data elements were not displayed correctly. Adding **$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");** resolved the issue.

Comment: good work, although you can convert it on utf8 using utf8encode function

Comment: Please stop using the deprecated `utf8` charset. Use `utf8mb4`